# Order by variable in Kohana

Tags: mysql, kohana

I know this is a silly question but I would like to know how to correctly add a variable to `order by` using Kohana, so far I have the following query where I have added the variable I want to the `where` clause, this works fine but when I apply the same for the order_by it doesn't work, do I have to specify it in a different way? I just need to order by the variables as these will be dynamically populated.

```
$geoquery = DB::select('store_id', 'city')
            ->from('mytable')
            ->where('latitude', '>=', $latitude * .9)
            ->and_where('longitude', '<=', $longitude * 1.1)
            ->order_by('ABS(`latitude` - 51.507202) + ABS(`longitude` - -0.223242))')
            ->limit(1)
            ->execute('mytable');
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use [***Database Expressions***](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/query/builder#database-expressions) for your `order_by`

```
$geoquery = DB::select('store_id', 'city')
            ->from('mytable')
            ->where('latitude', '>=', $latitude * .9)
            ->and_where('longitude', '<=', $longitude * 1.1)
            ->order_by(DB::Expr('ABS(`latitude` - 51.507202) + ABS(`longitude` - -0.223242))'))
            ->limit(1)
            ->execute('mytable');
```

According to docs

> There are cases were you need a complex expression or other database
>   functions, which you don't want the Query Builder to try and escape.
>   In these cases, you will need to use a database expression created
>   with DB::expr. A database expression is taken as direct input and no
>   escaping is performed